# How to hit and apply force to another object and make it move in corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I want to move an object with a force and that particular object will hit other object and make it move in the direction of the force applied and it will depend on the amount of force applied, i am trying to calculate amount of force applied with the amount of movement of mouse, but user can hit other objects several times without lifting the mouse drag button, please suggest any idea.. thanks...

```
  local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
physics.setDrawMode("normal")


local source
local target

local function onCollision( event )
     if event.object1.name == "object1"  and event.object2.name=="object2" or event.object1.name == "object2"  and event.object2.name=="object1" then
          target:applyForce(source.x_force, source.y_force, source.x_direction, source.y_direction )
     end
 end

Runtime:addEventListener("collision",onCollision)

local function move( event )
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    if "began" == phase then
        local parent = t.parent
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true
        -- Store initial position
        t.x0 = event.x - t.x
        t.y0 = event.y - t.y
    elseif t.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then
            t.x = event.x - t.x0
            t.y = event.y - t.y0

            source.x_direction=(t.x0-event.x)
            source.y_direction=(t.y0-event.y)
            source.x_force=t.x0
            source.y_force=t.y0

        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
        end
    end
     return true
end

 target = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
target.x = 200; target.y = 500
target:setFillColor(240, 200, 0)
target.name="object1"
physics.addBody(target,"dynamic",{radius = 70})

source = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
source.x = 650; source.y = 100
source:setFillColor( 240,125,0 )
source.name="object2"
physics.addBody(source,"dynamic",{radius = 70})
source:addEventListener( "touch", move)
```

Comment: Try the 'MultiPuck' project along with the corona sample codes.

Comment: Thanks.. krs but i do not want to use joints because they have elastic property, i want it to achieve it through force and for that i have updated my code and question please check it and give any suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have draggable bodies that interact with physics, you need to use [touch joints](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-physics-joints#Touch_joint). As krs mentioned, you can use the "CoronaSDK/SampleCode/Physics/MultiPuck" example to start with. Touch joints do have a bit of elasticity to their movement and they don't keep up with touch events.

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
physics.setDrawMode("normal")

local source

function move( event )
    local body = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    local stage = display.getCurrentStage()

    if "began" == phase then
        stage:setFocus( body, event.id )
        body.isFocus = true

        -- Create a temporary touch joint and store it in the object for later reference
        if params and params.center then
            -- drag the body from its center point
            body.tempJoint = physics.newJoint( "touch", body, body.x, body.y )
        else
            -- drag the body from the point where it was touched
            body.tempJoint = physics.newJoint( "touch", body, event.x, event.y )
        end
    elseif body.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then        
            -- Update the joint to track the touch
            body.tempJoint:setTarget( event.x, event.y )
        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            stage:setFocus( body, nil )
            body.isFocus = false            
            -- Remove the joint when the touch ends         
            body.tempJoint:removeSelf()            
        end
    end

    -- Stop further propagation of touch event
    return true
end

local target = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
target.x = display.contentCenterX
target.y = display.contentCenterY
target:setFillColor(240, 200, 0)
physics.addBody(target,"dynamic",{radius = target.width / 2})


source = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
source.x = display.contentCenterX
source.y = display.contentHeight - 100
source:setFillColor( 240,125,0 )
physics.addBody(source,"dynamic",{radius = target.width / 2})


source:addEventListener( "touch", move)
```

If you don't want the elasticity of a Touch joint and want your puck to move as fast as the user's touch, you have to do some of the physics yourself. You need to calculate the velocity of the touch to determine the force and the direction of impact to determine the direction to push the ball.

```
local sqrt = math.sqrt
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
physics.setDrawMode("debug")


local source
local target

-- Track velocity
local velocityTracker = {
    points = {}    
}

function velocityTracker:reset()
    self.points = {}
end

function velocityTracker:addPoint(time, x, y)   
    -- Only keep 10 points
    local count = #self.points + 1
    if count == 11 then
        count = 10
        for i=1,10 do
            -- Move older points to top
            self.points[i] = self.points[i+1]
        end 
    end
    self.points[count] = {time = time, x = x, y = y}
end

function velocityTracker:getVelocity(moves)
    if #self.points < 2 then
        return 0
    end

    local start = self.points[1]
    local totalVelocity = 0
    local now = system.getTimer()
    for i=2,#self.points do
        local finish = self.points[i]
        -- Use a vector to determine velocity
        local timePassed = finish.time - start.time
        local age = now - finish.time
        -- Only use recent points
        if age < 200 then
            local vector = {x = finish.x - start.x, y = finish.y - start.y}
            local distance = sqrt(vector.x^2 + vector.y^2)
            -- Calculate velocity
            totalVelocity = totalVelocity + (distance / timePassed)
        end
        start = finish
    end
    return totalVelocity
end

local function onPuckCollision( event )    
    if event.phase == "began" and event.other.isBall then
        -- Puck just hit a ball        
        local ball = event.other
        local puck = event.target

        -- Use a vector to determine direction of hit
        local vector = {x = ball.x - puck.x, y = ball.y - puck.y}
        -- normalize vector
        local magnitude = sqrt(vector.x^2 + vector.y^2)
        if magnitude > 0 then
            vector.x = vector.x / magnitude
            vector.y = vector.y / magnitude
        end        

        -- Use velocity to determine force
        local force = 10 * velocityTracker:getVelocity()

        local function smack()
            ball:applyForce(vector.x * force, vector.y * force, ball.x, ball.y)
        end

        -- We can't modify phyiscs in a collision handler so we
        -- `performWithDelay` to cause it to execute after this function
        timer.performWithDelay(0, smack)
    end
end

local function movePuck( event )
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    if "began" == phase then
        local parent = t.parent
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true
        -- Store initial position
        t.x0 = event.x - t.x
        t.y0 = event.y - t.y
        -- Save velocity tracking state
        velocityTracker:reset()
        velocityTracker:addPoint(event.time, event.x, event.y)
    elseif t.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then
            t.x = event.x - t.x0
            t.y = event.y - t.y0

            -- Track a movement
            velocityTracker:addPoint(event.time, event.x, event.y)
        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false
            velocityTracker:reset()
        end
    end
    return true
end


target = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
target.x = display.contentCenterX
target.y = display.contentCenterY
target:setFillColor(240, 200, 0)
target.isBall = true
-- Don't allow sleeping because a moving static body
-- won't always wake it if it's asleep
target.isSleepingAllowed = false 
physics.addBody(target,"dynamic",{radius = target.width / 2})


source = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
source.x = display.contentCenterX
source.y = display.contentHeight - 100
source:setFillColor( 240,125,0 )
source.isPuck = true
-- Use static body if you're going to move the object instead of
-- letting the physics engine move it
physics.addBody(source,"static", {radius = source.width / 2})

source:addEventListener("collision", onPuckCollision)

source:addEventListener("touch", movePuck)

local bounds = {
    left = -target.width,
    top = -target.height,
    right = display.contentWidth + target.width,
    bottom = display.contentHeight + target.height,
}

-- Reset ball position if it leaves screen
local function resetBall()
    if target.x < bounds.left or target.x > bounds.right or
        target.y < bounds.top or target.y > bounds.bottom
        then
        target.bodyType = 'static' -- Stop current movement
        target.x = display.contentCenterX
        target.y = display.contentCenterY                
        target.bodyType = 'dynamic' -- Make movable again

        source.x = display.contentCenterX
        source.y = display.contentHeight - 100        

        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
    end
end

timer.performWithDelay(500, resetBall, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks.. Cixate, but there is one issue when using this joint, because it has elastic property so i cannot use it in my project, as i move object with my mouse it does not move properly with my mouse i, have edited my question and code please tell whether by using force i can achieve the above result....

Comment: thanks Cixate.. Making puck static sometimes both target and source not collide with each other, but when i made it dynamic and give it a large density, they collide with each other but some times when colliding with puck all the objects of the disappears.. please see what is the issue behind that...

Comment: You can check how objects disappears from screen when you will change for i=2,#self.points do to for i=1,#self.points do, the same thing appears when i run my program multiple times, but i can't understand the reason.

Comment: Why would you change it to that? It's `i=2` on purpose because the first point is read with `local start = self.points[1]`

Comment: without changing to that also, some times when target and source collide they both disappear from the screen and program execution stops, this happens rarely.. why disappearing of objects occurs...